# Google maps markers labelClass animation not working properly

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am working on [this project](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://rawgit.com/IvanCoronado/running-statistics-from-Barcelona/master/dist/index.html#/). I have an [angular-google-map](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) directive. I am overwritting defaults markers with labelClass.
CSS is working fine but does not hover.

```
.marker {
    color: white;
    border: 2px white solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.marker:hover {
    background-color: #C52183;
    animation: pulse 1s;
}

/* ANIMATIONS */
@keyframes pulse {
  50% {

    transform: scale(4);
  }

  100% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

If you check the example you can see an animation but not with real color. I sometimes get the real animation.
The full project is [here](https://github.com/IvanCoronado/running-statistics-from-Barcelona).

pd: The problem can't be the animation, if i just try to change some css properties i dont get effect, so i think that the problem is with google maps and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this "bug".

The problem was on the MarkerWithLabel library but really isn't a bug, its just an impossibility (with this library). Checking the library we see   :

```
  // Set up the DIV for handling mouse events in the label. This DIV forms a transparent veil
  // in the "overlayMouseTarget" pane, a veil that covers just the label. This is done so that
  // events can be captured even if the label is in the shadow of a google.maps.InfoWindow.
  // Code is included here to ensure the veil is always exactly the same size as the label.
  this.eventDiv_ = document.createElement("div");
  this.eventDiv_.style.cssText = this.labelDiv_.style.cssText;
```

I just modified the library so i don't create invisible div anymore and also i intercept events with real label. Now it's working under my requirements.

[more info about the problem](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1574)

[demo working](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1574)